# Accessing XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml of the following format

```
<catalog>
 <cd>
  <title>CD name</title>
 </cd>
</catalog>
```

I can use xslt to get the element value using the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
<xsl:value-of select="title" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

But, I am trying to figure out the xsl code to read the xml in the following format:

```
<catalog>
 <cd title="CD name"/>
</catalog>
```

How do I do this? And if anyone can post some xslt tutorial link, it will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution. :)

Comment: Did you mean that instead of child element you want to select an attribute? Then you need `attribute` axis or its abbreviated form `@`. Example: `<xsl:value-of select="@title" />`

Answer (score 3):

```
I have an xml of the following format

    <catalog>
     <cd>
      <title>CD name</title>
     </cd>
    </catalog>

I can use xslt to get the element value using the following:

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <xsl:value-of select="title" />
    </xsl:for-each>

But, I am trying to figure out the xsl code to read the xml in the following format:


    <catalog>
     <cd title="CD name"/>
    </catalog>

How do I do this? And if anyone can post some xslt tutorial link, it will be much appreciated.
```

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="cd">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(@title, '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<catalog>
    <cd title="CD1 name"/>
    <cd title="CD2 name"/>
    <cd title="CD3 name"/>
</catalog>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
CD1 name
CD2 name
CD3 name
```

**For tutorials and books see my answer to this question**:

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589**

Answer (score 1):

Another site that is useful for tutorials is:
[link text](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/newto/)